# webkit overflow scrolling freeze scrolling after closing a modal

Tags: css, ionic-framework, modalpopup, webkit-overflow-scrolling

I am working on an ionic project. I have a page with css looks like the code bellow.

my page contain a button that opens a modal popup, when I close that model the page freezes and stops scrolling.

When I change -webkit-overflow-scrolling to "auto" the issue goes a way, but the scroll becomes hard and not smooth.

So I am looking for a solution that keeps "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" and enable scrolling in my page after closing the modal!
Would you please help?

--CSS :

```
my-page{
    .mypage-content{
        height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        ............
    }
}
```

Comment: " scroll-behavior: smooth; " add and check this work properly or not

Comment: I added it but still no scroll. In fact, I can click on buttons and tap in inputs areas but I can't scroll which is strange.